# Google basic Blue score

Tags: automl, google-cloud-automl, nmt

We are working on a project to train a Auto ML models for each language supported by Google. We would like to know the basic Blue score set by Google NMT for all the supported languages. (Not only Auto ML supported languages, but also the V2, V3 supported languages)